# Why is my assignment operator giving out a corruption error

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create a simple shared pointer for practice. Seems like I have an issue in the assignment operator and its crashing when I do this.
I am running this code on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)

```
_mtype = obj._mtype;
```

This is my code

```
struct foo
{
    foo()
    {
    }
    int a;
};

template <typename t>
class shared
{
    public:
    shared() 
    {
        _mtype = new t();
        counter = counter +1;
    }

    t* operator->()
    {
        return _mtype;
    }

    void operator=(const shared<t>& obj)
    {
        std::cout << "Assignment operator" <<std::endl;
        this->_mtype = obj._mtype; //Crashing here ? Why is this happening ?
        //return _mtype;
    }

    ~shared()
    {
        counter = counter -1;
        if(counter == 0)
             delete _mtype;
    }

    public:
    int counter = 0;
    t* _mtype = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    shared<foo> f;
    f->a = 12;

    shared<foo> g;
    g = f;   ///-------Issue starts here

    std::cout << "Finished";
}
```

This is the output that I get

```
Assignment operator
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001acdc20 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f950cf097e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7f950cf11e0a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f950cf1598c]
./a.out[0x40097b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f950ceb2830]
./a.out[0x400a19]
======= Memory map: ========
Finishedbash: line 7: 32173 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
```

Comment: "I have an issue" "its crashing" This is not an acceptable problem statement. Present a [MCVE] with output clearly annotated.

Comment: ok let me edit my question

Comment: Permission granted

Comment: just updated my post

Comment: Okay so it's a double free. Now run your program through your debugger, watching the value of `counter` in each object at each step. At the moment, you'll find that `counter` doesn't actually do anything (except underflow in the case of copy construction)

Comment: Your code crashes on double `delete` in the destructor. Yet you claim that the crash happens in the assignment operator. That is false. Use a debugger to find the exact location of the crash.

Comment: @AnT: OP probably observed that removing that line made the crash go away :P

Comment: @AnT thanks for pointing that out. I was under the impression that it was because of the assignment.

Comment: Add `<< std::endl;` after `"Finished"` and you'll see that printed too. Anyway, this is the perfect time to dust off that debugger and have it catch where the crash is happening.

Comment: Counter needs to be shared among objects. Typically it's stored in the same memory that is managed, you should keep a pointer to `struct{ int counter; T data };`. Multiple object can point to it, and increment/decrement the same counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't maintain properly the counter in assignment. Your old _mtype is leaked, and the new pointer gets an extra reference without the counter incremented.

Comment: Correct though fixing this will take a lot more than incrementing `counter` in the `operator=` definition. Unless I'm missing something, this design is terminally flawed.

Comment: Adding `counter = counter + 1;` fixed the problem

Comment: @MistyD: No, it didn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit any suggestions on why this design might be flawed ? I am just practicing and would love to hear suggestions

Comment: Yeah i still did not work on copy construction yet. I agree with you that this design might be flawed. But again the question was about why its crashing on a copy assignment operator

Comment: @MistyD: Now this reference has `counter` equal to 2, but when the other object goes out of scope it will still de-allocate the memory, making this reference invalid. And if you increment the other counter too, then you'll have a memory leak. You just can't do it this way, having separate copies of `counter`. The different references need to know about each other somehow.

Comment: The reason is I am generating two shared pointers with `new` which I shouldnt. The usage is wrong in this case

Comment: Study https://gist.github.com/tejainece/cb872b24828491c32dbd as an example

Comment: Don't forget to detach from the old object. And don't forget that this may actually be the same object though it is almost safe to miss.

Comment: @bipll: Copy assignment should not detach from the old object. These are shared pointers. `auto_ptr` used to do that, and it was terrible, which is why it was then removed from the language.

Comment: Hmm? When you assing a new value, the old one gets one reference less, huh?

Comment: Counter as an object property looks nice, too. :-)

Comment: Have you heard of sarcasm? Just curious.